# Fortran 90/95: How to convert a 3D array into a 1D array

Tags: fortran90, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D array NUM(0:9,0:9,0:9) which is used as a counter of sorts to keep track of how many molecules lie between certain coordinates. Anyways, the array ends up being a list of numbers which I want to make a histogram out of. If I write NUM to a file, and then open it up with my histogram program and read it in as a one dimensional array, everything is fine, but I would like to do it all in one program and I was wondering if there was a way to take all the numbers stored in NUM and make it into a 1 dimensional array?

My apologies if I'm not being very clear, I'm new to programming and I'm still learning along the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is a small array, you might want to try

```
    INTEGER :: i, j, k, n
    n=0 ! or 1?
    DO k=0,9
       DO j=0,9
          DO i=0,9
             num1d(n) = num(i,j,k)
             n = n+1
          ENDDO
       ENDDO
    ENDDO
```

Unpacking it would require using `num(i,j,k) = num1d(n)`.

**EDIT:** I misunderstood what you want. In order to do what you want, you would need have the position of the molecule and its distance *r* from the origin. Assuming this is known (or determinable), you would need to do the following:

```
    INTEGER :: i, j, k, n
    num1d=0
    DO k=0,9
       DO j=0,9
          DO i=0,9
             r = ....
             n = int(r)
             num1d(n) = num1d(n) + num(i,j,k)
          ENDDO
       ENDDO
    ENDDO
```

Where the `....` is whatever means you have to get the distance from the origin. The above also assumes that you have a bin width of 1, if you do want other widths, then you need to adjust `n=int(r)` appropriately.

Answer (score 8):

The statement

```
new_array = pack(old_array,.true.)
```

will flatten the rank-3 `old_array` into a rank-1 `new_array`.  You might declare this as

```
real(kind=...), dimension(:), allocatable :: new_array
```

replacing the `...` by your chosen method for specifying the kind of reals to use.

Comment: This flats in a column first order, how to flat it in an row first order?